# First index of longest ordered portion of a vector

Tags: r, indexing

I am looking to extract the longest ordered portion of a vector. So for example with this vector:

```
x <- c(1,2,1,0.5,1,4,2,1:10)
x
[1]  1.0  2.0  1.0  0.5  1.0  4.0  2.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0
```

I'd apply some function, get the following returned:

```
x_ord <- some_func(x)
x_ord
[1]  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0 10.0
```

I've been trying to leverage `is.unsorted()` to determine at what point the vector is no longer sorted. Here is my messy attempt and what I have so far:

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if( is.unsorted(x[i:length(x)])==TRUE ){
  cat(i,"\n")}  
  else{x_ord=print(x[i])}
}
```

However, this clearly isn't right as `x_ord` is producing a `10`. I am also hoping to make this more general and cover non increasing numbers *after* the ordered sequence as well with a vector something like this:

```
x2 <- c(1,2,1,0.5,1,4,2,1:10,2,3)
```

Right now though I am stuck on identifying the increasing sequence in the first vector mentioned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you want something like `rle(diff(x) > 0)` to find the longest run of increasing numbers.

Comment: @Gregor - you are correct. My oversight. Question changed to reflect.

Comment: @Gregor - something like this works for `x`: `x[ (max (rle( diff(x) > 0)[["lengths"]])-1) : length(x) ]` though it is a little messy. However, applying that to `x2` which includes numbers after the longest sequence results in those numbers being includes in the output because I can't figure how to set to right max index (i.e. `length(x)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
s = 1L + c(0L, which( x[-1L] < x[-length(x)] ), length(x))
w = which.max(diff(s))

x[s[w]:(s[w+1]-1L)]
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

`s` are where the runs start, plus `length(x)+1`, for convenience:

- the first run starts at 1
- subsequent runs starts where there is a drop
- we tack on `length(x)+1`, where the next run would start if the vector continued

`diff(s)` are the lengths of the `runs` and `which.max` takes the first maximizer, to break ties.

`s[w]` is the start of the chosen run; `s[w+1L]` is the start of the next run; so to get the numbers belonging to the chosen run: `s[w]:(s[w+1]-1L)`.

---

Alternately, split and then select the desired subvector:

```
sp = split(x, cumsum(x < c(-Inf, x[-length(x)])))
sp[[which.max(lengths(sp))]]
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Is it possible to annotate this a little more? It certainly does work but I am admittedly confused by the +/- 1L's...

Comment: @boshek Ok, I added some more notes. `1L` is just `1` as an integer. When subsetting vectors by a vector of element positions, it's best to use integers rather than floats, I guess.