# Finding index numbers of a consecutive run of numbers from a non-consecutive vector

Tags: r

Two part question:

## Q1

Say I had a vector like this:

```
y1 <- c(1:4,3,4:7,5,8:15)
y1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  3  4  5  6  7  5  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I would like to extract from this vector, starting from the lowest number, a vector of consecutive numbers. For `y1` here I am expecting this:

```
y_result=1:15
y_result
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

I am trying to use `is.unsorted()` but so far my skills are failing me. Here is my attempt so far. Subset a vector :

```
while (is.unsorted(y1) == TRUE) {
  y1 <- y1[which(diff(y1) > 0)]
}
y1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  5  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

This indeed does produced an unsorted vector. However, that pesky five is causing all sorts of havoc. I see how my `diff()` method is the problem but I'm not sure how to correct it. Just to be clear, I want to extract consecutive numbers dropping any numbers that don't conform along the way.

## Q2

For the above extraction, how would one extract the index values of the *original* data rather than the raw values. So for this example, I'd been looking for a return of:

```
>extract_function()
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

The idea here is that I'd be able to use those index numbers to extract the data from an original dataframe or vector. I can't use `match` or `%in%` for this because it will return multiple cases where condition is matched. In the example below, that pesky five reappears because `y2` matches 5 to both 5's in `df1$y1`:

```
  df1=data.frame(y1=c(1:4,3,4:7,5,8:15), res=rnorm(y1))
  y2=df1$y1
  
  
  while (is.unsorted(y2, strictly=TRUE) == TRUE) {
    y2 <- y2[which(diff(y2) > 0)]
  }
  
  df1[df1$y1 %in% y2,]

   y1         res
1   1 -0.24592395
2   2 -1.23183844
3   3  0.39394734
4   4  0.53695526
5   3 -1.76993425
6   4  0.14429303
7   5 -0.01816061
10  5 -0.83691178
11  8  0.27537953
12  9 -0.61817703
13 10 -2.17678870
14 11 -0.74117904
15 12 -0.70320352
```

Comment: Isn't Q1 basically the same as your previous question: [First index of longest ordered portion of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077448/first-index-of-longest-ordered-portion-of-a-vector) (which have a nice accepted answer)?

Comment: Similar answer but for some applications that approach is too aggressive. I also need an option that removes small chunks of non-increasing data. Excellent thoroughness though on finding that previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution which uses an accumulating reduce to find the indices first, then the values.

```
consec <- function(x) {
  idx <- unique(Reduce(function(p,i) if(x[i] == x[p]+1) i else p, seq_along(x), acc=TRUE))
  list(idx=idx, val=x[idx])
}
```

This works by keeping track of the index value of the last consecutive entry, updating it only when a new consecutive number comes. Thus, we have to filter to the unique indices for our final answer.

With example,

```
consec(c(1:4,3,4:7,5,8:15))

$idx
 [1]  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

$val
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

---

If you don't mean *consecutive* (as in integers with a difference of 1), but rather strictly increasing, then

```
ord <- function(x) {
  idx <- unique(Reduce(function(p,i) if(x[i] > x[p]) i else p, seq_along(x), acc=TRUE))
  list(idx=idx, val=x[idx])
}


ord(y1)

$idx
 [1]  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

$val
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15


y2 <- c(1.097, 1.101, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.151, 1.201, 1.245, 1.293, 1.379,
        1.482, 1.555, 1.616, 1.669, 1.719, 1.78, 1.842, 1.91, 1.949, 1.959,      
        1.955, 1.939, 1.911, 1.899, 1.903, 1.908, 1.922, 1.918, 1.907, 1.893,
        1.88, 1.877, 1.884, 1.895, 1.903, 1.914, 1.917, 1.913, 1.905, 1.9)

ord(y2)

$idx
 [1]  1  2  3  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$val
 [1] 1.097 1.101 1.120 1.151 1.201 1.245 1.293 1.379 1.482 1.555 1.616 1.669
[13] 1.719 1.780 1.842 1.910 1.949 1.959
```

Comment: I like this approach - however it seems to fall apart with a vector like this: `y2 <- c(1.097, 1.101, 1.12, 1.12, 1.12, 1.151, 1.201, 1.245, 1.293, 
1.379, 1.482, 1.555, 1.616, 1.669, 1.719, 1.78, 1.842, 1.91, 1.949, 1.959, 1.955, 1.939, 1.911, 1.899, 1.903, 1.908, 1.922, 1.918, 1.907, 1.893, 1.88, 1.877, 1.884, 1.895, 1.903, 1.914, 1.917, 1.913, 1.905, 1.9); consec(y2)`. I'm trying tease apart why but I thought I would share this here now.

Comment: I sense you don't mean *consecutive* but perhaps *strictly increasing*? See edits, do they match your expected output on `y2`? What exactly about this question now is not covered by your previous related question with accepted answer?

Comment: Yes i tripped myself up with consecutive versus increasing. This works great. The related question helped me find the first index of the first increasing sequence. Then this function will allow me to "clean" the data after that first index. I am trying to develop a small algorithm that satisfies a requirement that a vector be increasing without losing too much data.